# reddit praw scraping removing emoji and whwat encode to use

Tags: python, encoding, reddit, praw

Hey guys so i have this text file which i scrape from reddit using reddit praw:

```
Is that intended or a bug? WHAT. Iâ€™m on the way to my pubs.
Does first hit desolator remove ti shuffle thread? ðŸ¤”ðŸ¤” My brother works at valve and I confirm this
```

so i was wondering why i got that when i save my string to a txt, the way i save to txt are the following:

```
    with open(str(number)+".txt",'w', newline='',encoding="utf-8") as out:
        out.write(toPrint)
        out.close()
```

i'm not sure if i'm using wrong unicode, is there anyway so that i can remove these noises ? i'm sure the first one are I'm and the second one are an emoji from reddit, i prefer to just delete the emoji since that way seems to be easier.

Comment: `toPrint.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode()`

Comment: Thanks for reply, so do that first before writing to txt ?

Comment: yes or you can just include it like `out.write(toPrint.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode())`

Comment: that does the work thanks

Comment: okay awesome :)